# If condition inside echo

Tags: php

The IF condition inside echo statement does not work.

I get this error:

> Syntax error, unexpected `')'` in
>
> ```
>     echo ' <div class="panel-body">
>          '.$dec.'
>          '.(($ttype == "video")
>              ? '<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" 
>                 width="560" height="315"
>                 src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$only_id[1].'" frameborder="0"
>                 allowfullscreen=""></iframe>').'
>                 </div>';
> ```

Comment: you should add another value if it fails the condition `</iframe>':"")`

Comment: try this:  `echo ' <div class="panel-body">
    >                            '.$dec.'
    >          ('.$ttype.' == "video")?<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="560" height="315"
    > src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$only_id[1].'" frameborder="0"
    > allowfullscreen=""></iframe>').'
    >                           </div>';`

Comment: try this:- `echo '<div class="panel-body">'.$dec.(($ttype == "video"))?'<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$only_id[1].'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>:""</div>';`

Comment: If yur problem is solve than chose the best answer and mark as accepted

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate with variable. This will help you to avoid confusions

```
$html = '';
$html .= '<div class="panel-body">';
$html .= $dec;
$html .= ($ttype == "video")?'<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$only_id[1].'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>':'<!-- else part -->';
$html .= '</div>';
echo $html;
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your life easy and use like that:

```
<div class="panel-body">
<?php echo $dec; ?>
<?php
(($ttype == "video") ? '<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="560" height="315"
 src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$only_id[1].'" frameborder="0"  allowfullscreen=""></iframe>' : '');
?>
</div>
```

In your code, you are missing the else condition of Ternary operator.

**Solution with your code:**

```
echo ' 
    <div class="panel-body">'.$dec.'
    '.(($ttype == "video") ? '
        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="560" height="315" 
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$only_id[1].'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="">
        </iframe>' : '').
    '</div>';
```